# Importing vertica data to sqoop

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, sqoop, vertica

I am injecting vertica data to sqoop1 on a mapr cluster. I use the following query :

```
 sqoop import -m 1 --driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver --connect "jdbc:vertica://*******:5433/db_name" --password "password" --username "username" --table "schemaName.tableName" --columns "id" --target-dir "/t" --verbose
```

**This query gives me an error that**

```
Caused by: com.vertica.util.ServerException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "."
```

I read  https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!msg/cdh-user/xIBwvc_eOp0/TvhANQfvcv4J for getting more information regarding this, but wasnt quite helpful as they gave results on Sqoop2.

When I run this query :

```
sqoop import -m 1 --driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver --connect "jdbc:vertica://*******:5433/db_name" --password "password" --username "username" --table "tableName" --columns "id" --target-dir "/t" --verbose
```

**It gives an error: Relation "tableName" doesnt exist.**

I have added the required vertica-jdk jars in sqoop library too.

Any help regarding how to mention schema name in sqoop for vertica?

Comment: Did you have any additional output from the first one you could share?  Would like to see the generated INSERT or COPY being used.  You also might be able to find it in the query_requests table or the vertica.log.

Comment: I am unable to see the query in the query_requests table. But the error shown on the console has been updated in the post.

Comment: When you execute the first command, you don't get any INFO, DEBUG, and ERROR message lines?  I would have expected that the queries being executed would have been in an INFO line since you are using `--verbose`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SzzUMcX7 kindly refer this for more information. This contains the entire data displayed on console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the statement to --query and the schema.table is working fine there. So the statement is :

```
sqoop import -m 1 --driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver --connect "jdbc:vertica://*****:5433/dbName" --password "*****" --username "******" --target-dir "/tmp/cdsdj" --verbose --query 'SELECT t.col1 FROM schema.tableName t where $CONDITIONS'
```

Comment: Good to see you figured a workaround.  I'm still curious why it didn't work the original way, sqoop must be generating some incompatible SQL somehow.

Comment: Do you know some way through which we see the SQL which sqoop is running? Now I am facing issues with its export on vertica with some vertica syntax error. So it would be great to know what sqoop runs internally.

Comment: Generally, I thought you could see it with `--verbose`.  On the database, you can look at query_requests.

Comment: Nope, I am unable to find any export statements run by sqoop over there on my exported table.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the schema name to use in the connection string like this:

--connect "jdbc:vertica://*******:5433/db_name?searchpath=myschema"